# How i can cheat csrf form protect

Tags: forms, post, csrf

I need remove csrf-token protection from form.

Unfortunately, all the time I encounter an error, even though the token is properly charged.

Url:
https://rejestracja.kolporter.com.pl/auth/login

Here is my code:
http://pastebin.com/ntDVs7NT

I have error: 'Whoops, looks like something went wrong.'

Comment: its not my site, i dont have access to source code in server...

Comment: sb help? can i bypass csrf-token protection?